# cannot be cast to [B]; Same context (Default); Different Temp File

Tags: asp.net, iis, .net-4.0

I'm having difficulty finding why exactly the following error is happening. I'll outline the puzzling aspects below the error description.

[A]**ASP.common_resultmessagepanel_ascx** cannot be cast to
[B]**ASP.common_resultmessagepanel_ascx**.

**Type A** originates from 'App_Web_resultmessagepanel.ascx.38131f0b.2c4hpv_z, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
**in the context 'Default'** at location
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyWebApp\dc3e0df6\ba1606c8\App_Web_resultmessagepanel.ascx.38131f0b.2c4hpv_z.dll'.

**Type B** originates from 'App_Web_wz3shqfq, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
**in the context 'Default'** at location
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyWebApp\dc3e0df6\ba1606c8\App_Web_wz3shqfq.dll'.

The class referenced in the error is a web user control inheriting    from System.Web.UI.UserControl and implementing    System.Web.UI.ITextControl.
 The control is registered and used    on a master page. None of the parent master pages or implementing    pages have instances of the control.
 The class and the markup    page are both in the web application project.
 The exception does    not happen as a direct result of the application code, it happens    during internal .NET Framework code execution.
 The project is a    web application, not a web site.
 The web application is compiled    into a single binary, with culture specific resources compiled into    one binary per culture.

The context reported for each type in the exception is the same, but I was able to verify that when the exception occurs there are in fact 2 separate class definitions in the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder for the application.

The user control has always existed and was used in the application, but the exception first started happening after the user control was added to a master page.

The exception does not happen consistently. Once the temporary files get created, the exception will happen every time the page is requested. If anything causes the temporary files to be cleared or recreated, it is random as to whether the duplicate temporary class definitions/DLLs will be created again. This could be a web.config change, recycling the app pool, sometimes even just an updated/rebuilt web application binary.

The last bit of the stack trace:

```
   ASP.Default.__BuildControl__control35(Control ctrl) in C:\Projects\ABC.Web\App_Themes\Default\CheckBox.skin:3
   System.Web.UI.ControlSkin.ApplySkin(Control control) +12
   System.Web.UI.PageTheme.ApplyControlSkin(Control control) +119
   System.Web.UI.Control.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(Page page) +61
   ASP.masterpages_mymaster_master.__BuildControlpnlResults() in C:\Projects\ABC.Web\MasterPages\MyMaster.master:10
   ASP.masterpages_mymaster_master.__BuildControl__control2(Control __ctrl) in C:\Projects\ABC.Web\MasterPages\MyMaster.master:9
   System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container) +12
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.InstantiateInContentPlaceHolder(Control contentPlaceHolder, ITemplate template) +87
```

The supposed offending source (the only line in the skin file C:\Projects\ABC.Web\App_Themes\Default\CheckBox.skin):

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" SkinID="FormInput" CssClass="FormLabel FormInputCheckBox" />
```

At this point I don't know if this issue is caused by the solution, its configuration, IIS and the app pool, or something related to the actual temp file directory itself where maybe old files are not getting cleared out. I've verified that the temp folder is not being indexed by the OS.

I'm worried that in a production environment, the app pool will recycle or some configuration setting will change and cause those temp files to be recreated with the duplicate class definition, and thus the error. We can't have someone testing the application every time the app pool recycles and deleting temp files if the error occurs until the application loads correctly. So I need to find out what is causing the duplication, but at this point I don't really know where else to investigate.

Any ideas?

---

I've removed the user control from the master page, and put it directly into each of the pages that required it and were implementing the master page.

So far the exception hasn't happened again. I'm going to give it another couple days of test time to see if it crops up again.

I still want to know why the exception was happening at all. Anyone with in-depth knowledge of how IIS runs .net web apps, or how the temp files are created?

---

New theory!

While it is a web project with a compiled binary, the IIS instance I am running for development is pointed to the project folder. So the source code files are actually in the web path. I think IIS might be compiling the source code files into separate binaries, especially if the app pool recycles. Thus accounting for the duplicated temp files that are being created and the error.

Other developers were experiencing the errors while running the project from within visual studio. I don't know how this would account for those cases, but I wouldn't rule it out as being the cause either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a year and a half of seeing this error intermittently pop up for developers in our team, I've finally been able to gather enough data to draw some conclusions.

The key elements in the scenario causing the error are source code files in the web path, and low available memory on the dev machine that is running the application. The low memory condition causes the application pool to recycle or release memory more frequently than it would in a dedicated web hosting environment. When the memory containing the compiled web app code is released, and then a page is requested, the compiled code is reloaded into app pool memory. Since source code files are in the web path, .NET recompiles from the source code files and reloads into memory.

This situation does not happen in a dedicated hosting environment where only the compiled DLL and static files are deployed, and has never happened in our production environment. Additionally memory usage in a dedicated environment should ideally never reach a point where frequent app pool recycling is necessary.

The Visual Studio solution consists of several projects, and developers typically have multiple VS instances, a SQL Server Mgmt instance, and other sundry processes running which cause low available memory on dev machines. The lower the available memory, the more frequently and reliably the error will happen.

To clear the error state, an application pool flush / iisreset will clear out memory, and then a rebuild will usually fix the problem. If available memory is still low, the problem may persist until more memory is available in which to run the application. Simply closing down some applications or otherwise releasing memory back to the OS should do the trick.

I'm still not sure why running the app through Visual Studio's web server instead of IIS has same issue, but if it handles memory the same way IIS does, it stands to reason that the behavior is the same.

Comment: Absolutely right.  I just cleared all ASP.Net temporary files and re-cycle the IISExpress pool and the error went away.

Comment: @ulty4life I know this is an old posting, but I seem to be having a similar problem and clearing the temp files and recycling the IIS did not help... Any thoughts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294581/trying-to-recursively-find-a-control-with-if-is-type-wont-find?noredirect=1#comment37546121_24294581

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's happening in your case, but I had this happen to me under the following circumstances:

Website project type, not Web Application.

`/Controls` folder containing many ascx usercontrols.

`/Client/Controls` folder containing other ascx usercontrols, some of which register and reference `/Controls` usercontrols.

`/Controls/BadControl.ascx` using `/Client/Controls/DupedControl.ascx` as a child control.

The compiler runs into a circular dependency as it tries to compile each folder into a separate assembly.

`/Controls/BadControl.ascx` needs `/Client/Controls` to be compiled first.

`/Client/Controls` needs `/Controls` to be compiled first.

So the compiler punts and compiles `DupedControl.ascx` into its own separate assembly first. Then `/Controls`, then `/Client/Controls` *in which DupedControl still gets included*.

At this point there are two distinct Types for DupedControl in two separate assemblies. `DupedControl.ascx` (markup) points to the correct Type -- let's call it TypeA, in the folder's assembly -- while BadControl's reference points to the dupe TypeB in the small extra assembly.

**When a page using BadControl executes, DupedControl TypeA gets instantiated via the markup, but BadControl tries to cram it into a TypeB variable, resulting in the error you described.**

The solution is to move ascx files around to get rid of the circular reference. I can't remember for certain, but I think maybe the "single page assemblies" and "fixed naming" options might also resolve it.

All that said, Web Application projects compile to a single assembly, so I didn't think this kind of circular folder reference would be possible. Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely the same behavior as if it were a website project, but instead of happening on an actual compilation, it seems like it's happening as some sort of IIS/application pool caching. The bin folder just contains the single binary, but the temp file location contains binaries and other files containing class definitions seemingly at a folder level.

I'm going to try reorganizing or moving the control out of the master page and into the implementing pages.

The annoying thing is that since the problem depends on the temp files, I can't immediately prove that a change fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried setting `<compilation batch="false">` in web.config?

Comment: `<compilation batch="false">` doesn't seem to have any effect on either the build or the temp files created.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this issue with a Web Site (not Web Application) Project. It's frustratingly intermittent, and the only reliable (but unappealing) solution is to wipe out the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder while IIS is stopped. In my case I believe there is a circular reference but only when the pages/user controls are compiled in a particular order. We are using dynamic compilation, so it may even be dependent on the order in which the sites pages are browsed to. The code itself seems fine, though -- no  obvious circular reference that I can see...

Answer (score 0):

### SOLVED!

I had similar problem, caused from `LoadControl()` strange behaviour.. and **solved not instantiating my control before**.

strange but true..

---

```
MyUserControl myuc = new MyUserControl(); 
myuo = (MyUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/MyUserCOntrol.ascx");
```

**doesnt work**

---

```
MyUserControl myuc = (MyUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/MyUserCOntrol.ascx");
```

**works**

Comment: Please stop posting the same answer to multiple questions. If they are duplicates, flag them as such. If not, tailor your answer to the exact question posed.

Comment: In my case, the user control is not instantiated or loaded in the codebehind. It exists on the declarative aspx page, and is automatically instantiated the asp.net runtime page lifecycle. It also appears to be a manual build + duplicate runtime build problem.

Answer (score 0):

I belive we found a solution to this problem. We always tried fixing this by deleting the whole "Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder.

At some point this solution would no longer be good enough and the error kept popping up every 30 minutes or so. We found that deleting just the file responsible and then restarting the application pool of the application in question is a permenant fix (at least for us). So for you case you would delete the follwing file (**bold**) and then restart the applications application pool:

[A]ASP.common_resultmessagepanel_ascx cannot be cast to
[B]ASP.common_resultmessagepanel_ascx.

Type A originates from 'App_Web_resultmessagepanel.ascx.38131f0b.2c4hpv_z, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
in the context 'Default' at location
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyWebApp\dc3e0df6\ba1606c8\App_Web_resultmessagepanel.ascx.38131f0b.2c4hpv_z.dll'.

Type B originates from 'App_Web_wz3shqfq, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
in the context 'Default' at location
**'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\MyWebApp\dc3e0df6\ba1606c8\App_Web_wz3shqfq.dll'**.

This permenantly fixed the problem for us.

EDIT:
Found a permenant solution, at least for us.
In web.config look for  tag and add batch="false" to it. So it would look something like:

compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.2" batch="false"

The error never repeated after this.

Comment: I wouldn't really describe this as a permanent fix, but it would allow the application to run until another duplicate file gets generated.

See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15145461/135787

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right, but the fact is that with deleting the whole temp folder the error kept returning in 20 or so minutes every time.

By deleting just the above mentioned file the application is now up and running for over a week with no new problems.

Comment: Found a permenant solution, at least for us. In web.config look for tag and add batch="false" to it. So it would look something like:

compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.2" batch="false"

The error never repeated after this