# Trying to recursively find a control with if .. is [type], won't find

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, recursion, web-controls

I need to find a control of a parent, so I decided to do it recursively.  Via the object browser I see that the parent's first control contains the control I want.  Therefore, it should recursively call once, and then the first control on second iteration is the target.

When I debug, I indeed see that ctrl is of type ProgramHierarchy, but when it gets to the if .. is statement it fails the comparison... Any thoughts?  Does `is` not work like I thought?

```
private void FindProgramHierarchyCtrl(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl is ProgramHierarchy) // fails this even though 2nd iter of ctrl is a ProgramHierarchy
        {
            programHierarchyCtrl = ctrl as ProgramHierarchy;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ctrl.HasControls())
            {
                FindProgramHierarchyCtrl(ctrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

Ok so I changed it to check for the controls ID hardcoded just to make sure I'm not insane:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.ID == "programhierarchy")
    {
        programHierarchyCtrl = (ProgramHierarchy)ctrl;
    }
    else
    {
        if (ctrl.HasControls())
        {
            FindProgramHierarchyCtrl(ctrl);
        }
    }
}
```

And if finally goes in the If statement, but on the assignment I get the strangest exception I've ever seen... what is going on here?

```
[A]Stuff.Things.Web.ProgramHierarchy cannot be cast to [B]Stuff.Things.Web.ProgramHierarchy. Type A originates from 'Stuff.Things.Web, Version=1.0.5282.29772, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Stuff\Communities In Schools\Solution\Stuff.Things.Web\/bin/Stuff.Things.Web.dll'. Type B originates from 'Stuff.Things.Web, Version=1.0.5282.29772, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Stuff.Things.web\94104cc5\724c3b9d\assembly\dl3\55541b78\a421c72d_458bcf01\Stuff.Things.Web.DLL'.
```

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx), it works like you expect it. Have you stepped through the code line by line to make sure it executes as expected? Right now you're not returning anything. Usually when you find it you should return it.

Comment: The "is" operator will return false when the cast throwns an exception. Did you checked that?

Comment: As @mason said, your code there is incomplete. You might be using your "programHierarchyCtrl" variable in an unexpected way.

Comment: Do you have two types with the name `ProgramHierarchy`, or another type with a really similar name?

Comment: @Servy All, I updated the post with a screenshot from my debugger, the watches indicate that it should pass the if, but it skips over...

Comment: it appears that you have a Casting problem in this line `programHierarchyCtrl` perhaps you could change it to look something like this `((ProgramHierarchy)ctrl).someProperty = someValue`

Comment: @DJKRAZE It never even gets there, it skips over the if as if it evaluated as false.  Never actually runs that line when stepping through.

Comment: well sounds like controls might be null have you debugged it.. also try changing parent.Controls to `this.Controls` see what happens

Comment: @DJKRAZE Did you see the screenshot I posted? Look at the watches, its for sure not null.

Comment: It's skeptical that you wouldn't step into an if statement that the debugger is telling you is true, are you sure your code matches the binary you are debugging against?  Are you attaching to a service that might not have that line of code?

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia I'm not attaching manually, I do a fresh Rebuild All and then  Start with Debugging

Comment: I would make sure there are no old dll of the file that you are debugging. rebuild all does not always delete these files also a clean then rebuild all "might" work

Comment: @Delta Good thought, did a clean, rebuild and then start with debugging with same results :/

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Check edit 2, I think you might have been on to something, got a super strange exception.

Comment: @Hershizer33 Looks like somehow you have 2 references to the same thing, one in the GAC and another in your "c:/Stuff/" dir, maybe remove the reference and re-add it to make sure everything is pointing to the same place.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Thanks, that sounds like it could be possible, I'll check that out tomorrow at work!

Comment: You might try another test where you publish the web application to a new IIS folder/website, run it and attach to that process. The error may not happen in that case. Are you running your code through IIS or through the VS virtual server?