# Strange exception: Active Project's DLL being referenced in two places?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I hope its okay to do this, but after some help in my last question it basically raised a new question as to what's happening.  [Here's the original question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294581/trying-to-recursively-find-a-control-with-if-is-type-wont-find?noredirect=1#comment37546121_24294581)

As you can see, I'm getting a very strange exception, and it seems to be the reason my type comparisons were not returning true:

> [A]Stuff.Things.Web.ProgramHierarchy cannot be cast to [B]Stuff.Things.Web.ProgramHierarchy. Type A originates from 'Stuff.Things.Web, Version=1.0.5282.29772, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'LoadNeither' at location 'C:\Stuff\Communities In Schools\Solution\Stuff.Things.Web/bin/Stuff.Things.Web.dll'. Type B originates from 'Stuff.Things.Web, Version=1.0.5282.29772, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\Stuff.Things.web\94104cc5\724c3b9d\assembly\dl3\55541b78\a421c72d_458bcf01\Stuff.Things.Web.DLL'.

Keep in mind that `Stuff.Things.Web` is the active project.  How could it possibly be referencing the DLL of the active project (result of the build) from anywhere other than the bin folder?

Comment: Are you using some kind of external caching or out of proc session? Could it be that the version in cache/session might come from another source than you would expeceting it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, can you clarify?  How would I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with an ASP.Net solution I was deploying: The DLL being referenced was strongly named and and the correct version but I was still suffering from casting errors. I fixed it by setting 'Copy Local' on the DLL properties in Visual Studio to 'False'. That seemed to force the solution to use the same instance of the DLL.